# iOS in-app purchases - best way to tell if user has purchased

Tags: ios, persistence, in-app-purchase

I need to set a global variable when a user makes an in-app purchase. I could use NSUserDefaults, and just have a key called "Purchased", but that doesn't seem very secure.

What is the best way to securely store data so that I know whether or not users have made a purchase?

For example in a particular view I need to know whether or not to display a "Purchase" button. Obviously it should be hidden if they've already made the purchase.

Answer (score 3):

For secure data you should use the iOS keychain. Here's the documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think this helps for iOS.

Comment: Sure it does. The keychain exists on iOS, and it's the most secure native way of storing data. A user wouldn't be able to edit this data easily, so storing the data in the keychain is the best and most secure method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store that information. There is a method to restore all the user purchases. Look for [restoreCompletedTransactions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

You can check all the user's purchases in your view and then show the "Purchase" button for all the items that can still be bought.

**UPDATE**:

Oh! I misunderstood your question. The above method will get you the purchases the user has made in case of an app reinstall for instance. Regarding your question, it is completely fine to store information relative to the purchased products in `NSUserDefaults` to give the user the goods, levels or whatever he has paid for.

I recommend [this](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) step by step tutorial that helped me implement in-app purchases to answer all your questions.

Comment: Will this work even if the user is not connected to the internet?

Comment: No, it won't, but the user won't be able to Purchase anything either or retrieve any other information like the prices, so there is no point in showing what items can be bought. If there is no internet connection just notify the user and keep your buttons disabled.

Comment: Yes, but if they make a purchase one day, and come back to the app some time later and don't have a connection, the interface should still be able to show them that they already made the purchase and allow them to use the new functionality. I have to be able to store that somehow.